# phpspreadsheet will not save excel sheet from the browser

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I must be missing something... I've installed `phpspreadsheet` on my Fedora 28 in my project folder and ran the samples in Firefox and Chrome browsers.  I can read the excel sheets, they can be saved locally (being prompted to save as), but when I run the "hello world" example it dies when it hits the line

```
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

When I run

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/samples
```

the files get written to the system (in the `/tmp` folder), but running the same samples from the browser, the files do not get saved.  I'm guessing it's a permissions issue, but i'm not getting any error. Apache is being run as the apache user.

I couldn't find anything on the web, so does anyone have any idea?